# Pandas: Mean of columns with the same names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns like:

```
['id','name','foo1', 'foo1', 'foo1', 'foo2','foo2', 'foo3']
```

I would like to get a new dataframe where columns sharing the same name are averaged:

```
['id','name','foo1', 'foo2','foo3']
```

Here column foo1 would be the average of the three columns named foo1 in the original dataframe, foo2 would be the average of the two columns named foo2 and foo3 would be just foo3

Note: id and name are not numeric and I have to keep them.

Comment: Set index on id and name, groupby col names, mean(), reset index should make it

Comment: But what if I have a lot of non-numeric columns like id and name? Is it ok to set the index by all the non-numeric columns?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic idea is that you can group by your columns names and do mean operations for each group.

I saw some comments for your question and tried to give you different ways to achieve the goal. (**Solution (3) is the best I found!**)

(1) Quick solution. If you have very limited columns that are non-numeric, and own unique names, e.g., columns `id` and `name`. What you can do is:

First set index `['id', 'name']` to preserve them,

```
df = df.set_index(['id', 'name'])
```

then use `DataFrame.groupby` function on `columns`, set `axis=1` (iterate over each column), apply `mean` function for each group.

```
df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).mean()
```

And finally, reset index to recover `['id', 'name']` columns

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Here is a sample code:

```
In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame([['001', 'a', 1, 10, 100, 1000], ['002', 'b', 2, 20, 200, 2000]], columns=['id', 'name', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3'], index=list('AB'))

In [36]: df = df.set_index(['id', 'name'])

In [37]: df = df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).mean()

In [38]: df = df.reset_index()

In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
    id name  c1   c2    c3
0  001    a   1   55  1000
1  002    b   2  110  2000
```

(2) Complete solution. If you have lots of columns that are non-numeric and unique named, what you can do is:

First transpose you dataframe,

```
df2 = df.transpose()
```

Then you do group by operations (on its index and `axis=0`), but carefully handle each groups: for these numeric groups, return their mean value; and for these non-numeric groups, return their first row:

```
df2 = df2.groupby(by=df2.index, axis=0).apply(lambda g: g.mean() if isinstance(g.iloc[0,0], numbers.Number) else g.iloc[0])
```

And finally, transpose back:

```
df = df2.transpose()
```

Here is sample of code:

```
In [98]: df = pd.DataFrame([['001', 'a', 1, 10, 100, 1000], ['002', 'b', 2, 20, 200, 2000]], columns=['id', 'name', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3'], index=list('AB'))

In [99]: df2 = df.transpose()

In [100]: df2 = df2.groupby(by=df2.index, axis=0).apply(lambda g: g.mean() if isinstance(g.iloc[0,0], numbers.Number) else g.iloc[0])

In [101]: df3 = df2.transpose()

In [102]: df3
Out[102]: 
  c1   c2    c3   id name
A  1   55  1000  001    a
B  2  110  2000  002    b

In [103]: df
Out[103]: 
    id name  c1  c2   c2    c3
A  001    a   1  10  100  1000
B  002    b   2  20  200  2000
```

You need to `import numbers`

**More notes:**

(3) All in one! This solution is the best I found:

```
df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda g: g.mean(axis=1) if isinstance(g.iloc[0,0], numbers.Number) else g.iloc[:,0])
```

I tried to handle each group for the un-transposed groups, that is,

```
df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).apply(gf)
```

And

```
gf = lambda g: g.mean(axis=1) if isinstance(g.iloc[0,0], numbers.Number) else g.iloc[:,0]
```

I failed before, because I do not carefully hand the axis. You must set `axis=1` for `mean` function, and return columns for non-numeric groups.

Thanks!

Comment: This gives me an error about "no numeric types to aggregate" columns are like: id : object, name: object, foo1: float64, foo1: float64, foo1: float64, foo2: float64, foo2: float64, foo3: float64

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! Solution 3 is really what I needed, the check to verify if the datum is a number is what I couldn't do. Thank you!